# Headphones plugged in, but audio comes through speakers Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, headphones

I have dual-booted Ubuntu 22.04 from Windows. My headphones worked as normal on windows, but when I plug them in whilst using Linux, the sound still comes from the speakers.

I believe the headphones are indeed still being
[detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZXdD.png) but the audio itself still comes from the speakers rather than through the headphones.

I have also tried using [pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOY3z.png), but to no luck so far.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your pavucontrol shows not all outputs, actually it doesn't show what's used right now. Also report from alsa-info would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, here it is http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=096adb49aa001c567e9450c121ada86b905b4296

Comment: I'm not an expert, but shouldn't only one of those be running? Either Pulseaudio or PipeWire.

Comment: Also just to confirm: when you connect headphones, they don't get sound even if you manually select them for output?

Comment: Some quick googling seems to suggest that both of them running is OK? And yes, when I connect headphones, they don't get sound no matter what I do

Comment: No, it's OK to have them both installed, but running should be only one of them. Your alsa-info shows both are running. PipeWire is supposed to replace Pulseaudio and provides replacement modules. If both are running, they might conflict, because both are supposed to manage underlying hardware. I doubt that's the cause of your problem, but nevertheless.

Comment: Oh right - any ideas what the problem could be then?

Comment: If system detects and correctly reports presence and usage of all devices, I have no ideas beyond checking device settings in alsamixer. You may try your luck tweaking `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` like adding `options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi` (just look for a proper model name).

Comment: A quick fix for me was to disconnect all other audio outputs except my headphones (until you can find a better solution).

Answer (score 0):

On some machines, you will need to go into the `Settings > Sound` to reselect the output device to be the headphones.

The output device setting also sometimes gets out of sync, and may still say `"speakers"` when the headphones are plugged in and working.

Comment: I have checked that, but that doesn't seem to be the solution here

Answer (score 0):

On my Lenovo ThinkStation P920 dual Intel Xeon 8160 Workstation with NVIDIA Corporation GP106GL [Quadro P2000]:

Experiencing this problem with not switching to only headphones when they are newly plugged in. I'm finding that both outputs (headphones and rear output speakers) play simultaneously. What I have to do to get only headphones output is to unplug the rear speakers (or turn them off, if they have that option).

The settings, sound, output device headphones selection only seems to be allowing headphones output, but DOES NOT disable the rear output.

No known "user" fix, seems to me to be a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for my case. After working on my machine for a long time, it will stop working someday. But with this command, it was fixed:

```
$ pacmd load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

[System does not switch automatically to my headphones](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468900)